# Use virtualenv in python script

Tags: python, cgi, virtualenv

I've set up a virtualenv in my working directory and I installed matplotlib in this environment.
Now I want to use this virtualenv for a script that I've written.

```
#!venv/bin/python

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Without the import command, it works, but I get "ImportError: No module named matplotlib.pyplot".

Edit: I use mod_cgi.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install matplotlib into your venv?

```
venv/bin/pip install numpy
venv/bin/pip install matplotlib
```

Other than that, there is nothing wrong with your script.

On a side note, you may want to reconsider the location of your venv, if indeed the location is inside your http root, or worse, a CGI directory.