# How to make Python 3 virtual env activated for all the time, even when not using console/putty

Tags: python

I have shared web hosting space with python 2.6.6 pre configured, now I have installed python 3, I have created the virtual env for the same & activated it.

**My question is -** How can I keep the python3 virtual environment **activated all the time**, even when am not using the console/putty.
The problem is I have imported couple of libraries to python3 & want to use it, but if my console/putty is closed my header line in .py files has to be pointed back to #!/usr/bin/python >>but this points to python2.6.6.

Whereas I want the python3 should always work. All the users coming to my website, their requests needed to be processed by python3 instead of python2.6.6.

Really searched a lot but could not get this specific information.
Thanks...

Comment: Why don't you install your python3 libraries globally and point your .py files to `#!/usr/bin/python3`?

Comment: some system utils may also use `python`, so if you set your virtualenv python as default you can create system trouble for your self, so safety way is to change `#!/usr/bin/python ` in your scripts to `#!virtaulanv_path_to_python`

Comment: I am running via cgi concept.. I have html page on click of button sending data to the .py file which has import cgi, cgitb libraries.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27695501/use-virtualenv-in-python-script

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking of this in the wrong way. If they're coming to your website, then they're using your web app. It's only that that needs to run under the virtual environment, which you would configure in its own startup script (eg the wsgi script).